# How do you setup table structure for auto increment primary key with revision?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, auto-increment, composite-key

C# interface accessing Sql server db.

I have a table with a composite key ID and revision.

When I "insert" a new record I want to auto increment the ID.
When I "update" the record I want to actually insert a new record but increment revision.

What is the proper table settings for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done in the past is actually use a trigger for `UPDATE`. It would copy all the values into a new record and increment the version column. I would also have an indexed column that would serve as a key, but not a primary key so that all revisions would be tied together.

Comment: Thank you I will look into triggers.

By indexed column to server as key, do you mean have an additional column, like row number in addition to the ID and revision number.  If this column was auto incremented, do I manually set my ID value?